# App doesn't work on 4.0.3 but it works on 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-sdk-2.3

I write an app and it works properly on android 2.3.3 , but it doesn't work on android 4.0.3.

I specify minsdk="10" and targetsdk="15" in my AndroidManifest file.

I am using .net web service in my app and I'm getting error on this page.

```
myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ihtiyacsec);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SektorList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

SektorList is null.

I'm using ksoap2 for access my web service.

Here is my function

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut=request;
        envelope.dotNet = true;     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

       try {

       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
       SektorList = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

      for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){          
               SektorList[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();     
      }      
} 
        catch (Exception e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

When I debug the project , androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope) is not work and compiler jump to catch block.

I know my soap action is true (same codes work in 2.3.3).

I dont know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a very common problem. As of Android HC+ you aren't allowed to perform heavy network operations in your main UI thread. To solve this problem you could: remove the "targetsdk" tag from your manifest(not recommended) or just use an asynctask for your network operation.

Comment: I try delete targetsdk tag from my manifest but still it doesn't work

Comment: I try use asynctask for this operation then I will write result here, thanks

Comment: hi I have some problem with using asynctask. please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878599/multiple-asynctasks-issue-on-android-spinner

Answer (score 1):

You're performing a (potentially slow) network operation on the main thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher, this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Honeycomb or above, because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.

You could use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to get around this, loading the data in `doInBackground(..)`.

Comment: I try use asynctask for this operation then I will write result here, thanks

Comment: hi I have some problem with using asynctask. please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878599/multiple-asynctasks-issue-on-android-spinner